# how to store Objective-C 2 D NSMutableArray in swift array?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, nsmutablearray

I am trying to store Objective-C 2 D NSMutableArray in swift array but getting following error

"Type "any" has no subscript members"

My objective-C 2D array is like

```
NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I can access its value in objective-C like

```
 combinedArray[1][2]
```

But getting error in swift :
swift code is like

```
let  pinCodeProbabilityMatrix:NSMutableArray = combinedArray as NSMutableArray
        print("pinCodeProbabilityMatrix \(pinCodeProbabilityMatrix[0][0])")
```

In log I am getting array correctly store in swift array but not able to print same

Is there any other way to fetch value in swift?

Comment: Is your nested array contains dictionary?

Comment: Yes correct ..it cause any issue?

Comment: Yes from swift 3 you need to tell the compiler type of variable before using it, so you cannot subscript `pinCodeProbabilityMatrix[0]` because it will give you result as any type.

Comment: Can you please suggest solution I am new in it? should I store one by one like in first variable only first array and in second nested array?

Comment: Don't use `NS(Mutable)Array` in swift use swift's native array in your case it is `[[[String:Any]]]`.

Comment: it is not allowing to store NSMutableArray in obj-c to store in swifts    [[[String:Any]]]

Comment: No, you don't get me, It will allow you to create `NSMutableArray` in swift but when you subscript it from swift3 it will return Any as object and any doesn't allow subscripting with it, so it is batter to use Swift native type array.

Comment: Yes agree, But I am getting Array from objective-C file

Comment: You cannot go continuos subscript with array you need to break your statement. `let array = pinCodeProbabilityMatrix[0] as! NSArray` and then access array `print(array[0])` personally I don't suggest to go with NSArray in swift.

Comment: Right...but in my scenario of objective with swift its not possible i think

Comment: Then you can go with two line code like my above comment.

Comment: is this ok if I keep 2D array without Dictionary ? can i access directly then?

Comment: What do you mean by that are you storing custom object inside that array or  some string?

Comment: I have array of array and dictionary inside nested array so I can place another array instead of dictionary..becomes 3 D array

Comment: No it is still 2d array because dictionary is with your nested array not with nested-nested array.